# How can I improve the sliding effect on my website header?  

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown, slideup

This is how I made the sliding effect on this page: [dmg-01.net](http://dmg-01.net):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".trail-text").attr("style", "display:none;");
  if ($("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five")) {
    var pixies = $("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five");
    $("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five").hover( function() { 
      $(this).find(".trail-text").slideDown("fast"); 
    }, function() { 
      $(this).find(".trail-text").slideUp("fast"); 
    });
  };
});
```

I would like to improve it because it's not as graceful as I want. I think it would be better if only one slide effect occur at the same time with no overlapping.

On the other hand, I tried to accomplish the same effect this way:

```
$(function(){
  $("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"}, {queue:false, duration:111});
    },function() {
      $(this).animate({height: "44px", width: "44px"}, {queue:false, duration:333});
    });
  });
});
```

I discarded it because I don't know how to set "auto" for height and the content inside the "hidden" elements are visible outside the element.

How can this be improved?

According to my purpose, I prefer to animate with CSS properties the descendants of the elements. This is how I tried to do it but it isn't working. Why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".trail-text").attr("style", "display:none;");
if ($(".#one,#two,#three,#four,#five")) {
$("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five").hover(
function() { $(this).find(".trail-text").animate({height: "100%", width: "444px"}, {queue:false, duration:111}); },
function() { $(this).find(".trail-text").animate({height: "0", width: "444px"}, {queue:false, duration:333}); }
);
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I improve the effect [with this trick](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/).

However, I would have preferred `.animate` instead of `.slideDown/Up` so I can add CSS properties. Anyway, the animation is smooth and I'm satisfied. Thank you for your advice and improvements!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery "[queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)" method to chain the animations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five").hover(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"}, {queue:false, duration:111});
    },function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({height: "44px", width: "44px"}, {queue:false, duration:333});
    });
});
```

So you can skip an additional loop